# Lucene.Net search like a071,a072,a073

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Enviroment :

Lucene.Net 3.03

Visual Studio 2010

---

I've been stuck on this problem for hours at this point and I can't figure out the problem.

i build some index named "Stores" , the format like below ,

a075,a073,a021....

each string represent the id of shop , and it Separated by "," ,

i would like search "a073" , and it will return matched data if the "Stores" include "a073"

thanks in advance

```
static RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();


public void BuildIndex()
{

    IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.Add(new Field("PROD_ID", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
    doc.Add(new Field("Stores", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        doc.GetField("PROD_ID").SetValue(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        doc.GetField("Stores").SetValue("a075,a073,no2" + i.ToString());
        iw.AddDocument(doc);
    }

    iw.Optimize();
    iw.Commit();
    iw.Close();
}

private void Search(string KeyWord)
{

    IndexSearcher search = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);

    QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Stores", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));

    Query query = qp.Parse(KeyWord);

    var hits = search.Search(query, null, search.MaxDoc).ScoreDocs;


    foreach (var res in hits)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("PROD_ID:{0} / Stores{1}"
                                    , search.Doc(res.Doc).Get("PROD_ID").ToString()
                                    , search.Doc(res.Doc).Get("Stores").ToString() + "<BR>"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardQuery` and include wildcards.
Google for Lucene regular expression search to find some code to use regular expressions in your query... there is a contrib implementation called `Contrib.Regex.RegexTermEnum`.

An alternative would be a multivalued field, instead of a string separated by comma you would pass an array into it. This will be split and indexed by Lucene and you can query it in the same manner as a normal field. In addition you can query it multiple times, e.g. multiField:ValueA and mutliField:ValueB ...

Comment: hi,Ela , i know i can use the wildcard like "*" , but is there the other ways to solve it ~ thanks

Comment: @Holmes see last edit, use multivalued field should do it for you

Comment: hi , Ela , do you mean use the MultifieldQueryFieldParser ? but its seem like search in multi field . Could you give me some sample ~thx!

Comment: here is one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128200/lucene-net-field-contains-mutiple-values-and-who-to-search
you actually have to add multiple fields with the same name and different values to the document and lucene.net it seems.

Comment: Thanks for your advise , its a good way to solve this question!